# manually trigger touch event

Tags: javascript, events, touch

I searched for the past 30 minutes, but didn't find a solution.

I want to trigger a `touchstart` event on an element.

This fires the `touchstart` event:

```js
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');

e.initMouseEvent("touchstart", true, true, window, 1, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY,
    ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);

target.dispatchEvent(e);
```

*Note that the variables are defined by my function*

But there's a problem with that. The `event` object doesn't have a `touches` property. So something like this won't work:

```js
var touch = e.touches[0];
```

Is there a way to trigger a `touchstart` event manually (it should work on Android >= 4.0 and Chrome with touch enabled [DevTools]) ?

*Please note, that I do NOT want to use any framework like jQuery. With jQuery it's easy to create a `touchevent` on an element ;)*

Comment: Just for sanity, why do you need to generate an event?

Comment: Well, lets say that I have a container. This container has many subcontainer which are hidden. When I touch on this container, one subcontainer becomes visible, and as long as I touch the container, I should be able to move the subcontainer by moving my finger. So when I touch on the container, a `touchstart` event should be created on the subcontainer.

Comment: That sounds like something that should be fairly easy to do without faking events. If your model knows about the container dependency you can control all from the single original event.

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated and I can't do it your way :/ I have to fake the event...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [W3C](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html)

```
var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
```

Then, also change

```
e.initMouseEvent();
```

to

```
e.initTouchEvent();
```

As you've created a `touchstart` event.

The W3C link says:

> Some user agents implement an initTouchEvent method as part of the TouchEvent interface. When this method is available, scripts can use it to initialize the properties of a TouchEvent object, including its TouchList properties (which can be initialized with values returned from createTouchList). The initTouchEvent method is not yet standardized, but it may appear in some form in a future specification.

So you'll might have to resort to `e.initUIEvent('touchstart', true, true);`
In addition, the official spec also states that the `TouchList` object is *optional*, and can be created manually using the `createTouchList` method. To add a *touch* to that list, you'll have to call the `createTouch` method, where you'll pass all coordinates and such:

```
6.1 Methods

#createTouch
Creates a Touch object with the specified attributes.
Parameter | Type        | Nullable | Optional | Description
view      | WindowProxy |   ✘      |    ✘     |
target    | EventTarget |   ✘      |    ✘     |
identifier| long        |   ✘      |    ✘     |
pageX     | long        |   ✘      |    ✘     |
pageY     | long        |   ✘      |    ✘     |
screenX   | long        |   ✘      |    ✘     |
screenY   | long        |   ✘      |    ✘     |
Return type: Touch

#createTouchList
Creates a TouchList object consisting of zero or more Touch objects. Calling this method with no arguments creates a TouchList with no objects in it and length 0 (zero).

Parameter | Type  | Nullable | Optional | Description
touches   | Touch |     ✘    |    ✔     |
Return type: TouchList
```

If that doesn't work, you could try this:

```
var e = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
e.initUIEvent();
```

should work, it makes more sense than `createEvent('MouseEvent')` at any rate...
But for testing purposes, why not open your chrome console and check `Emulate touch events`, plus override user agent to Android 4. (Ctrl+Shift+j > click the gear bottom right corner, and select Overrides, there you'll find all the settings you need)

Since the touch-events have a long way to go, still in terms of their becoming standardized, it turns out the `touches` property is *not* RO (yet?), so you can use this quick-fix (which the OP found and used with the desired result):

```
var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
e.touches = [{pageX: pageX, pageY: pageY}];
```

Which, I think (I can't believe it if it weren't the case) is faster than:

```
e.touches = e.createTouchList(
    e.createTouch(window, target, 0, pageX, pageY, screenX, screenY)
);
```

Comment: First, thank you for this answer! :) I have tried that, too, but it didn't work... There's no good documentation on `createEvent('TouchEvent')`. :/ And in Chrome I get this error: `Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9`. And with `[DevTools]` in my question I meant that I had dev tools touch enabled. ;)

Comment: @AndreM96: Found it: the `TouchList` object is optional, and you'll have to manually create a `Touch` object using the `createTouchList` and `createTouch` methods respectively

Comment: Thanks! That works. I found a simple workaround which I now use: `e.touches = [{pageX: pageX, pageY: pageY}];` (`e` is the created event). But your solution is definitely better!

Comment: @AndreM96: I wouldn't say that, if passing an object literal works just as well, then your sollution is probably the one to go for. An object literal is cheap and fast, while the DOM is bulky, counter intuitive, and often slow, so I'll edit my answer and include your workaround

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem These methods `createTouchList` have been deprecated so I am unable to use your suggestion.

Comment: Few problems with this: a) e.touches may be not overridable for touch event (so in Phantom 2.1), b) createEvent('TouchEvent'), createTouch etc. are not supported in most current browsers (Chrome, FF). Chrome seems to implement support for Level 2 touch events (https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/) so you can use constructors to construct events, but it is only Chrome.

Comment: @GeorgiiIvankin I'm sorry, but really: look at how old this answer is: 2013. Almost 4 years ago, `createEvent` was *not* deprecated, [as it is today](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent). If things have changed, which they have, it might be worth while updating an existing/accepted answer. I've moved on to back-end development only. I can't keep answers like this up to date.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem nothing personal, didn't mean you were wrong. It's just that I feel too busy to properly update the answer and instead leave the comment so that it might be useful to those who find this answer.

Answer (score 20):

I know this has been answered, but I too struggled to find an answer to this problem and the accepted answer didn't work for me. In the end, the solution I found is really very simple and has support across browsers:

```
var e = new Event('touchstart');
target.dispatchEvent(e);
```

That's it. Couldn't be easier.

Comment: what is the target?

Comment: @scord `target` is an element you want to dispatch your event for

Comment: Unfortunately with current level of support amongst browsers this seems to be the most valid solution, although not very robust. Just create a generic event and manually fill all the properties you need as if it was a "real" touch event.

Comment: How do you set the coordinates of the touch event?

Comment: @KevinHe `target` defines the coordinates of the element that will receive the event.

Comment: dispatchEvent' is undefined),

Answer (score 5):

I have come up with this solution (javascript native), works for me

```
var el = document.getElementById('myDivId');
// desktop
el.click();

// mobile
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
        // createEvent(), event.initEvent() are Depricated see Ref: [enter link description here][1]
        // var event = document.createEvent("Event"); 
        // event.initEvent("touchstart", false, true);
        // event.initEvent("touchend", false, true);
        // So the solution is:
        var event1 = new Event('touchstart');
        var event2 = new Event('touchend'); 
        el.dispatchEvent(event1); 
        el.dispatchEvent(event2);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In 2019, we can use [`TouchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/TouchEvent) and [`Touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/Touch).

> `Touch` is an experimental technology

For example,

```js
const touch = new Touch({
  identifier: "123",
  target: target,
});

const touchEvent = new TouchEvent("touchstart", {
  touches: [touch],
  view: window,
  cancelable: true,
  bubbles: true,
});

target.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
```

I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/cs09g/f9971ed6ddb720d66deb1fc8da7c42d4). try it simple.

Comment: Hm.  I can't seem to get your gist to work; I put it in a CodeSandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/simulatetouchevent-test-i0vzx?file=/src/index.js

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @DanOverlander You added `click` event on the element. `click` and `touch` are different. If you replace `click` to `touchstart` or `touchend` it'll work as epxected.

Comment: giving me error on chrome : Cannot set property touches of #<TouchEvent> which has only a getter

Comment: @user889030 could you share your code? my working fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/3qubaek0/

Comment: @ChaseChoi thanks your fiddle is working ok looks like there was issue in my code i updated it according to your fiddle now its working ok . many thanks

Comment: @ChaseChoi if you not mind can i share my code with you , am struggling with one webpage canvas am not able to trigger touch on it although it should be working ok as you demo in jsfiddle snippet. struggling my head from week with it but no clue why its not working :(

Comment: @user889030 Sure, but not sure I'm able to fix it.

Answer (score -5):

We can trigger like this:

```
$playBtn.bind((is_touch_device) ? 'touchstart' : 'click', playfunction);
```

Comment: Please, check the short description of the JavaScript tag: _"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected"_, just hover your mouse over it. There is no jQ tag, no jQ answers...

Comment: I just updated my question. Yes, I don't want to use any kind of framework. ;)