# simulate touch events for html5

Tags: javascript, android, html, multi-touch

I am building an html5 game and I would like to send multi touch events to the browser programmatically.

My idea is to setup a node server and forward the events to the webpage. Is there any library that already does this or could I simulate such events?

For example [`this page`](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/8/) is multi touch enabled but on the desktop you can't interact as there is only mouse. If I could simulate the events, then I can interact with the objects. I am looking for something like this... Any pointers are helpful...

I tried using ::

```
var e = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
e.initUIEvent('touchstart', true, true);
e.touches = [{pageX: x, pageY: y}];
```

I got no response with the above and then I used this

```
var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
e.touches = [{pageX: x, pageY: y}];
```

I get an error if I am not in mobile emulation mode but when I move to mobile emulation mode I get no response

I also tried :: [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059860/manually-trigger-touch-event) with no luck

**Update**

[From here](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/8/)

```
var type = 'move'; // or start, end
var event = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
event.initEvent('touch' + type, true, true);     
event.constructor.name; // Event (not TouchEvent)

var point = {x: 10, y: 10 };
event.touches = [{
    identifier: Date.now() + i,
    pageX: x,
    pageY: y,
    screenX: x,
    screenY: y,
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y
}, {  identifier: Date.now() + i,
    pageX: point.x,
    pageY: point.y,
    screenX: point.x,
    screenY: point.y,
    clientX: point.x,
    clientY: point.y}]

    dispatchEvent(event);
```

This worked but only in `mobile emulation mode`

With this a touch event is raised but with a `real` touch I have the following data

```
TouchEvent {metaKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false, ctrlKey: false, changedTouches: TouchList…}
```

But with the custom event the changedTouches element null and yes I tried setting the `e.touches to e.changedTouches`

```
TouchEvent {metaKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false, ctrlKey: false, changedTouches: null…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018151/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-touchevent-in-chrome-41)

```
var type = 'move'; // or start, end
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('touch' + type, true, true);     
event.constructor.name; // Event (not TouchEvent)

var point = {x: 10, y: 10 };
event.touches = [{
    identifier: Date.now() + i,
    pageX: x,
    pageY: y,
    screenX: x,
    screenY: y,
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y
}, {  identifier: Date.now() + i,
    pageX: point.x,
    pageY: point.y,
    screenX: point.x,
    screenY: point.y,
    clientX: point.x,
    clientY: point.y}]

    dispatchEvent(event);
```

This worked but only in `mobile emulation mode`