# Create TouchEvent from Points and dispatch with Dart

Tags: dart

I have a scenario in which I get a List of Points that need to be converted to a TouchEvent which needs to be applied to the DOM to fire the appropriate listeners. The receiving end works with touchEvent.targetTouches[].

I have found these answers on Stackoverflow for JavaScript:

[manually trigger touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059860/manually-trigger-touch-event)

[How do I programmatically create a TouchEvent in Chrome 41?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018151/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-touchevent-in-chrome-41)

```
var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
e.touches = [{pageX: pageX, pageY: pageY}];
```

In Dart this would roughly translate to:

```
TouchEvent e = new Event.eventType("TouchEvent", "touchstart");
```

`e.touches` is read only, so how do I set the coordinates?

Comment: Sounds like the similar story to the "create keyboard events". You could try `new CustomEvent('touch')` and pass data using the `detail` parameter. https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.1/dart-html/CustomEvent-class.html No idea how much control you have over the event receiver to work with such events.