# Programmatically "touchstart" react-tappable elements from the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to programatically `touchstart` an element from the console (natively, or with a library like jQuery) in the same way one can programatically click element? For example, `$('div').touchstart()`

Currently attempting this with react-tappable also - [raised here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-tappable/issues/116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manually trigger touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059860/manually-trigger-touch-event)

Comment: I believe the 2nd answer has what you are looking for.