# Is it possible to touch event on screen programmatically without rooting the device?

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

I tried to call touch event programatically but not working

```
fun callTouchEvent(x: Long, y: Long) {
        val e = MotionEvent.obtain(
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            x.toFloat(),
            y.toFloat(),
            0
        )
        onTouchEvent(e)
    }
```

Could anyone please help,

how to trigger touch event programatically if we pass co-ordinates parameter to touch event?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059860/manually-trigger-touch-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [manually trigger touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059860/manually-trigger-touch-event)

Comment: You can refer to this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902985](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902985)

Answer (score 0):

You can not call touch event programatically if application is not handled by you. If it is your application you can call `view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);` or `view.performClick();`